# Why can't my website form connect to the database after I transferred it to another server?

Tags: php, database, wordpress, configuration

I just transferred a website from one server to another. the website is on WordPress.

On our website, we have a form that is broken and I am not sure why.

When I try submitting the form, it returns an error in the DOM (the specific string is "Could not connect !")

There is no error in the console. I checked the string that is being returned and I found it in a configuration file. The data in this file were connected to the former database (on the former server). It makes sense that we were not able to make a connection.

However, I updated the database information and it still returns the same string. I used the data from the wp-config file.

Here is the code:

```
$link = mysqli_connect("IP address", "userName" ,"password");
if (!$link) {
    die('Could not connect !');
    exit();
}
else{
    mysqli_set_charset($link, 'xxx');
    mysqli_select_db($link, "xxx") or die('Could not select database.');
    }

?>
```

Comment: To make your code more robust (unless you're on PHP 8.1 or above where this is already enabled by default), add `mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);` before your `mysqli_connect()` command, and this will ensure that errors with your SQL connection and queries are reported correctly to PHP automatically. That way, you might see the specific connection error (rather than just the generic, invented message which the code above outputs when the connection fails), which should give you a better clue about what's wrong and how to fix it.

Comment: Thanks @ADyson, it returns me a POST error 500. I will explore this.

Comment: In that case, if you don't see the error message in the front-end, it's very likely that the error is recorded in a PHP log file on the server